# Internal Server Error after changing htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am getting a Internal Server Error after changing my .htaccess.

What I want is I want to change the following URL:

```
www.mydomainname.com/map/Change?internal_id=abc123
```

To:

```
www.mydomainname.com/map/Change/abc123
```

When I open `www.mydomainname.com/map/Change/abc123` I get a `Internal Server Error`. The other link is still accessible.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Change/(.*)$ Change.php?internal_id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

php_value session.cookie_domain .mydomainname.com
```

When I open the error_log I cant see any logs that are related to this issue.

Does someone know why the page isnt working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing

```
RewriteRule ^Change/(.*)$ Change.php?internal_id=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^map/Change/(.*)$ map/Change.php?internal_id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
#dont show .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#dont show .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#making clean urls
RewriteRule ^map/Change/abc123 map/Change?internal_id=abc123
```

Comment: I tried it like you said. I still get the same error

Comment: is your htaccess at your root directory

Comment: Yes. The .htaccess is in my root directory. The codes that I use to hide .php are working. Only the ?internal_id= part is not working

Comment: It is still not working. I dont know if it is related to this issue, but I have entered the `php_value` part at the end of your code. When I navigate to my website I can see that the Login script is not working anymore. (I am working with subdomains: For logging in I am using login.mydomainname.com. After logging in the script is redirecting me to pages.mydomainname.com). I need the `php_value` part to use the session for all my subdomains. When I navigate to pages.mydomainname.com I can see that the session is not working anymore

Comment: For `map/Change/abc123` I dont need any session. The fact is that I still get an Internal Server Error. It doenst matter if I open it from a subdomain or not.

Comment: sessions are for one domain. Your subdomain is like another domain so your session for  login.mydomainname.com cannot work for pages.mydomainname.com unless after login you pass the session value with json and then set the sessions on the second subdomain

Comment: have you tried clearing your cache or cookies or even change browser after using those code above